# How does arrow functions behave when the body is a single line?

Tags: javascript, promise, arrow-functions

I wanted to know when arrow functions have a single line, the curly braces and the return keyword can be omitted, it implicitly returns whatever is there. But what if I don't want to return anything.

For example in the following code snippet, the `first .then` should return `response.json` and this is what the code does, the line is implicitly returned. But in the `second .then` I don't want to return the `console.log` but according to me it is also being implicitly returned.

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

My question is have I understood this properly? And does this really matter because it won't change the results of my program? And if it does what's the way around?

Comment: `console.log` does not return anything

Comment: @Berto99 it does return undefined

Comment: @jonatjano - Pleased to see that that's [specified behavior](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) now. Not that it was likely to change, but... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ain't it specified behavior that function without return statement returns undefined ?

Comment: @jonatjano - `console.log` wasn't originally specified at all, so it could have returned `undefined`, or `console` (for chaining purposes), or the message(s) you logged, or something else altogether in any given env. So for a time, relying on it returning `undefined` was a leap of faith. Now it's *specified* that it returns `undefined`. (But answering your question: Effectively, yes. At the JS spec level, there's a small diff between a function without a `return` and one that explicitly returns `undefined`, but the result of calling them both is `undefined`, so it's just a spec quirk. :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what if I don't want to return anything.

Your best bet there is to use the verbose form (with curly braces) without a `return`. But note that even then, calling a function *always* ends up with a result (even if the function doesn't `return` anything). That result is `undefined` if the function doesn't return anything.

You *could* (ab)use the comma operator, but I discourage you from doing so, and you need `()` to do it:

```
.then(json => (console.log(json), void 0));
```

..not least because it's more verbose than

```
.then(json => { console.log(json) });
```

(Of course, `console.log` [returns `undefined`](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#logger) anyway, so... :-) )

---

> My question is have I understood this properly?

Yes, you seem to (other than a **minor** quibble with the word "line", see the "Side Note" below).

> And does this really matter because it won't change the results of my program? And if it does what's the way around?

It certainly doesn't matter with a function like `console.log` that returns `undefined.` If nothing is using the promise returned by that final `then`, then no, it doesn't matter.

---

FWIW, the **real** problems with the code in the question are:

1. It doesn't look for HTTP success before calling `json`. This is a footgun in the `fetch` API: It only rejects the promise on *network* errors, not *HTTP* errors.
2. It doesn't handle rejections.

Fixing those:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);
    }
    return response.json();
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle/report error
  });
```

---

Side note:

> ...when the body is a single line?

Lines aren't relevant here. What's relevant is that the first non-whitespace character after the `=>` is or isn't a `{`. If it is, the arrow function has a *function body* and explicit `return` is required if you want to return something other than `undefined`. If it isn't, the arrow function has a *concise body* which is a single expression, the result of which is returned from the function.

Answer (score 2):

> have I understood this properly?

You understood properly, everything you said is good

> does this really matter because it won't change the results of my program?

it doesn't really matter, it doesn't change the result of your program, it could change it if you had a 3rd `then` as the value returned by the `console.log` would become the parameter for your 3rd `then` callback

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .then(value => /*value is the value returned by console.log which is undefined*/)
```

but you're not forced to use this value it's up to you

> what's the way around?

if you don't want to get the value returned by the operation then you can add curly braces

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {console.log(json)})
  .then(value => /*still undefined because a function without return still return undefined by design of the language*/)
```